# VBA объединение макросов событий листа

Tags: excel, vba

Встала задача сделать в экселе форму с автоматической проверкой введенных данных. Гугл помог с нужными макросами (нашел похожий пример и заточил под свои нужды). Но вот с их объединением косяк, по отдельности работают отлично, вместе завести не получается.

Что здесь не так? Нужно порядка 10 макросов на листе объединить, а я даже 2 не могу подружить пока.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range, d As Range
    Set Target = Intersect(Target, [F:F]) '<<< столбец'
    If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each c In Target
       If c Like "[A-Z][A-Z]#######" Then '<<< маски ввода'
       Else
       c = ""
           If d Is Nothing Then Set d = c Else Set d = Union(d, c)
       End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Not d Is Nothing Then
       d.Select
       MsgBox "В выделенную ячейку (ячейки) были введены неверные значения. Формат ввода `KH1234567`. Буквы ЛАТИНСКИЕ!!!", vbExclamation
    End If

    Dim cc As Range, dd As Range
    Set Target = Intersect(Target, [G:G]) '<<< столбец'
    If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each cc In Target
       If c Like "####-##-##" Or c Like "####-#-#" Or c Like "####-##-#" Or c Like "####-#-##" Then '<<< маска ввода'
       Else
       cc = ""
           If dd Is Nothing Then Set dd = cc Else Set dd = Union(dd, cc)
       End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Not dd Is Nothing Then
       dd.Select
       MsgBox "В выделенную ячейку (ячейки) были введены неверные значения.'
 Формат ввода `1985-4-18` (ГГГГ-ММ-ДД или ГГГГ-М-Д или ГГГГ-М-ДД)", vbExclamation
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: И что не получается? Какие сообщения об ошибке?

Comment: это один макрос, а где второй?

Comment: Они должны работать на разные диапазоны. 1 макрос на номер паспорта, второй на корректность введенной даты.

Comment: Dim cc As Range, dd As Range
Set Target = Intersect(Target, [G:G]) '<<< столбец
и далее.... это и есть второй. Если первый убрать - все работает по столбцу G:G, но мне нужно кучу столбцов проверять.

Comment: Сделайте два макроса. Зачем в один лепить.

Comment: @nick_n_a потому что это макрос листа

Comment: А валидация встроена в excel вам точно не подходит? Поставьте защиту с валидатором на дату, это не сложно.

Comment: http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2018/06/18/0021/2230/1407158/58/ac25c5b4e5.png

Comment: где в экселе есть валидация например что текст введен на латинице? Не видел никогда.

Comment: Я сказал **дату** проверкой данных. А текст макросом. Дату так - Данные-проверка данных-тип - Дата. И не прийдётся макрос два-в-одном.

Comment: Мне еще полей с 10 валидировать, в том числе текстовые. У меня есть пример с 2 макросами, работающими подряд, но не могу у себя по такому же примеру подружить их...

Comment: Используйте проверку формулой. Формулу на паспорт можно написать.

Comment: Используйте отладчик - отладчик позволит понять что пошло не так.

Comment: Я уже написал все выше. Зачем заново изобретать велосипед? Если Вы не знаете как, не значит что это невозможно. Не работает подозреваю из-за If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub, т.е. если изменений в первом диапазоне не было, то выходит из макроса вообще, а не идет далее. Но как переписать не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Макрос, реагирующий на определенное событие листа, в модуле одного листа может быть только один. Но можно разграничить диапазоны и при изменениях в них запускать отдельные процедуры:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("F:H,K:K,S:S,W10:Y250"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Row < 2 Then Exit Sub ' исключаем срабатывание на "шапку"'

        With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .EnableEvents = False: End With

        Select Case Target.Column
        Case 6
            ' код для столбца F'
        Case 7
            ' код для столбца G'
        Case 11, 19
            ' код для столбцов K, S'
        Case Is > 20
            ' код для столбцов правее T'
        Case Else
            ' код для других указанных диапазонов, указанных в Application.Intersect'
        End Select

        With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .EnableEvents = True: End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2018/06/18/0021/2230/1407158/58/74d3b4252f.png

Comment: При изменении ничего не происходит(

Comment: Вопрос о том, как объединить процедуры для разных диапазонов в одном коде события листа. Это и показано. Что там не получается в самих процедурах - это другой вопрос.

Comment: Так по отдельности они работают, если убрать вторую...

Comment: Добавьте в case 6 например код "MsgBox "Привет!!!", vbExclamation" Ничего не происходит при изменении любой ячейки в столбце F. Так что процедура здесь не при чем.

Comment: Ошибка: *Target.Row > 1*: если изменения в строке ниже первой, то выход из процедуры. Нужно *<2* (смотрите по данным). Исправил. Но у Вас в коде правильно (*<2*). На тестовом - работает

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался вроде :)

Comment: Под *Case* можно разместить только цикл, остальное вынести за пределы *Select Case*